# Problems with segmentation fault C++

Tags: c++

Every time I get to the line "g_wordArray[countNumber] = new Word(wordInputTemp)" in the readTextFile function, I get a segmentation fault. I've already looked through another post on the site describing reasons for a segmentation fault, and I either have missed what is in my code that is causing it, or it's not one of those reasons. Also, in the class Word, I have nothing, so it is not something happening there. Everything is declared inline and it's all blank.

```
#include "Word.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int FILE_PATH_SZ = 512;
Word **g_wordArray;
int g_arrSz = 50;
Word** allocateArray();
void readTextFile(Word** g_wordArray);
char fileDir[FILE_PATH_SZ], wordInputTemp[256];

int main()
{
    g_wordArray = allocateArray();
    readTextFile(g_wordArray);
}

Word** allocateArray()
{
    Word** g_wordArray = new Word*[g_arrSz];
    return g_wordArray;
}

void readTextFile(Word** g_wordArray)
{
    ifstream fileInput;
    fileInput.open("sample.txt");
    int countNumber = 0;
    while (fileInput >> wordInputTemp)
    {
        g_wordArray[countNumber] = new Word(wordInputTemp);
        countNumber++;
    }
    fileInput.close();
    return;
}
```

Word Class:

```
class Word
{
public:
    Word(const char *word);
    ~Word();
};
```

Word constructor and destructor:

```
#include "Word.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
Word::Word(const char *word)
{
    len_ = strlen(word) + 1;
    ptr_ = new char[len_];
    strcpy(ptr_, word);
}

Word::~Word()
{
    if (ptr_ != 0)
    {
        delete [] ptr_;
        len_ = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `Word`?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why are you using global variables?

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string` and `std::vector`

Comment: I added the definition of `Word`.

Comment: Your class `word` does nothing. What is the point of it? (and it is declared at the bottom). Does this code actually compile?

Comment: What is the value of `countNumber` when `g_wordArray[countNumber] ` seg faults? I bet it is >=50

Comment: The code complies fine, and `word` is used for a bunch of stuff, but I was having problems with my program after multiple revisions with no problems and I was trying to diagnose the problem. So, I commented out everything in the class and still making it compile.

Comment: It gets the seg fault on the first cycle, so 0.

Comment: The it must be something in the `word` constructor - perhaps post that code

Comment: In the posted code, `fileDir` is not set to any valid value.

Comment: I added the constructor and destructor and added what the variable fileDir would be into the post.

Comment: `if (ptr_ != 0)` - You do not need this test. `delete` is happy to delete null pointers

Comment: I didn't even think of that, thanks.

Comment: Run it in a debugger to see where it goes wrong. If you can't add console output to isolate where the crash happens. Apart from that you should look at how to write modern C++, this can be rewritten to be tons cleaner. Just use a vector of strings, and move it around or pass it by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you never store a value in the global variable.  In the function that allocates the array, you declare a local variable with the same name.